# PyOpenGL cannot render any vao

Tags: python, opengl, vbo, pyopengl, vao

I have spent almost 2-3 hours trying to figure out why I am not getting a rectangle renderered. I am using pygame for making a window, and opengl for rendering onto the window.

what should be happening is a red background with a blue rectangle, but what I am seeing is just the empty red background.

this is the code I used below.

am I uploading things to the shader wrong? or did I miss something.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
import numpy as np
print("import sucessfull")

vertex = """
#version 460 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

out vec4 fColor;

void main(){
    fColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
"""
fragment = """
#version 460 core
in vec4 fColor;
out vec4 color;
void main(){
    color = fColor;
    //gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
"""

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.init()
    display  = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 1000)
    glClearColor(1, 0,0,1)
    glTranslatef(0,0,-5)

    #############################3
    vertexID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(vertexID, vertex)
    fragmentID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(fragmentID, fragment)
    glCompileShader(vertexID)
    glCompileShader(fragmentID)
    program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(program, vertexID)
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentID)
    glLinkProgram(program)

    positions = [
        0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0
    ]
    indexes = [
        2,1,0,
        0,1,3
    ]
    vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    glBindVertexArray(vao)
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array(positions, dtype=np.float32), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array(indexes, dtype=np.float32), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, 0)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    ################################

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        #render here
        glUseProgram(program)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
        glUseProgram(0)
        #***********
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(40)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the indices must be integral and correspond to the type specified in the draw call (`GL_UNSIGNED_INT`). You have to create a NumPy array with the type `uint32` instead of `float32`:

<s>`glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array(indexes, dtype=np.float32), GL_STATIC_DRAW)`</s>

```py
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, np.array(indexes, dtype=np.uint32), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

---

If a named buffer object is bound, then the 6th parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. But the type of the parameter is a pointer anyway (`c_void_p`).

So if the offset is 0, then the 6th parameter can either be `None` or `c_void_p(0)` else the offset has to be caste to `c_void_p(0)`:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, 0)`</s>

```py
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, None)
```

There is a similar problem with [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml). The last argument is treated as a byte offset:

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)`</s>

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

---

`gluPerspective` and `glTranslatef` set the deprecated fixed function pipeline matrices. This instructions do not make any sense when you use "modern" shader program. Remove this instructions. With modern OpenGL you have to use [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variables.